# Force member initialization in static const struct in c

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I am using a `struct`s for storing different configurations and I would like to force the initialization of all members. I mean not let the compiler do it (to zero), but the progammer explizitly.

A compiler error would be best but a warning would be fine as well. I am using Segger clang for arm.

Any tips about how to achieve this?

Since I would like to use designated initializers, `-Wmissing-field-initializers` does not work in this case. See: [Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

```
typedef struct{
    int option_1,
    int option_2,
    ....
} config_t;

// this is fine
const config_t config_1 = {
    .option_1 = 10,
    .option_2 = 20,
};

// this should generate a warning
const config_t config_1 = {
    .option_2 = 20,
};
```

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you want to force the changes in an array of static types or do you want to see the compiler shouting at you for trying to do it?

Comment: Does `-Wmissing-field-initializers` help?

Comment: @Davide he wants second one

Comment: Thank you Kanony. Then I think all you need is to enable your compiler's warnings

Comment: @EugeneSh. nops, from the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html): _This option does not warn about designated initializers, so the following modification does not trigger a warning: `struct s { int f, g, h; }; struct s x = { .f = 3, .g = 4 };`_ It will warn in this case: `const config_t config_1 = {20};`

Comment: In `// this should generate a warning` do you mean because you did not explicitly initialise member `option_1`? It's implicitly initialised to `0` even when a local variable.

Comment: As @WeatherVane already pointed out, all fields _are_ initialized even if you do not specifiy them explicitly. So the question is, _why_ do you want them to be initialized explicitly?

Comment: Like you say @WeatherVane, i did not explicitly initialise every single member. I would like to warn about that.

Comment: @koder Since it would like to make sure if someone creates a new config they dont miss some field. Or if fields are added to the structure, they have to be added to all configurations.

Comment: If you want to initialise every member, then designating them is irrelevant, and @EugenSh comment should work with this style - `const config_t config_1 = { 1 };` ?

Comment: Could you generate the proper code from an input file?  You can control the data that way and ensure all values are initialized.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think this would be messier in the end, since configurations have more than 50 members and its hard to make sure you setting the correct ones.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Could do that yes, but i would like to avoid having another tool if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's no particularly elegant way to do this programmatically. Best bet is to use a static initializer tool. (There's for example a MISRA-C:2012 rule that can be checked for, requiring that all elements of a struct must be initialized explicitly.)

With pure standard C, well...
Since this struct won't have any padding, I suppose you could cook up something fairly ugly like this:

```
#define CONFIG_INIT_LIST1 10, 20
#define CONFIG_INIT_LIST2 10

_Static_assert(sizeof (int[]){CONFIG_INIT_LIST1} == sizeof (config_t),
               "CONFIG_INIT_LIST1 wrong number of initializers.");
_Static_assert(sizeof (int[]){CONFIG_INIT_LIST2} == sizeof (config_t),
               "CONFIG_INIT_LIST2 wrong number of initializers.");

// this is fine
const config_t config_1 = {
    CONFIG_INIT_LIST1
};

const config_t config_2 = {
    CONFIG_INIT_LIST2
};
```

This gives the compiler error

> error: static assertion failed: "CONFIG_INIT_LIST2 wrong number of initializers."